# Converting individual x,y coordinates into individual polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, convert, coordinates

I am currently struggling to convert x,y coordinates into individual polygons. Feature polygon and points to line is not what I am trying to do. I have sampled vegetative plots on the landscape and have recorded the X,y coordinate for the bottom left corner of the sampling polygon. I have then taken the bearings from the baseline and first transect to orientate the polygon and I have the length measurements for the baseline and transects of the polygon. I have all the information to produce and orientate a polygon from each GPS coordinate, but can not seem to find a function in arcGIS to accomplish this task. Obviously I could create feature polygons for each x,y coordinate and define each length and angle, but I have a several hundred x,y coordinates to convert to polygons. I have added a table of the information I want to use, and a photo to visually depict what I want to do.

[image: site_characteristics_table][image: site_diagram]

Comment: This can be done using Python. Take a look at the examples at the bottom of: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polygon.htm

Comment: Project corners, add xy. Compute 2 more pairs of xy. Merge 3 points datasets and dissolve to multipoint using wp. Use minimum bounding geometry. Note some of your records aren't rectangles, fix it first.

Comment: Could you add the table as text?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using Bearing Distance to Line and Add Geometry Attributes. First the four sides are created and then turned into a polygon by Minimum Bounding Geometry rectangle.

Alot of code, but seems to work.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.qualifiedFieldNames = False
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\geodatabase.gdb' #Change

intable = r'Plots' #Your table imported to the workspace
outfc = r'Plotfields'

input_spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
output_spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(32616) #Change if you want

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path=arcpy.env.workspace, out_name=outfc, geometry_type='POLYGON', spatial_reference=output_spatial_reference)

arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(table=intable, in_x_field='GPSLONG', in_y_field='GPSLAT', 
                                  out_layer='xylyr', 
                                  spatial_reference=input_spatial_reference)

arcpy.Project_management(in_dataset='xylyr', out_dataset='projected', 
                        out_coor_system=output_spatial_reference, 
                        in_coor_system=input_spatial_reference)

arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(Input_Features='project', 
                                       Geometry_Properties='POINT_X_Y_Z_M')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(intable, ['WP']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table='project', out_view='project_view', 
                                       where_clause="""{0} = {1}""".format(
                                           arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='project', field='WP'),row[0]))
        #Create first line
        arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(in_table='project_view', out_featureclass='line1', x_field='POINT_X', y_field='POINT_Y',
                                               distance_field='Transect_width', distance_units='METERS',
                                               bearing_field='Transect', id_field='WP', spatial_reference=output_spatial_reference)
        #  add end coordinates
        arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(Input_Features='line1', 
                                               Geometry_Properties='LINE_START_MID_END', 
                                               Length_Unit='METERS', 
                                               Coordinate_System=output_spatial_reference)
        #Create second line
        arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(in_table='project_view', out_featureclass='line2', x_field='POINT_X', y_field='POINT_Y',
                                               distance_field='Baseline_length', distance_units='METERS', 
                                               bearing_field='Baseline', id_field='WP', spatial_reference=output_spatial_reference)
        #  add end coordinates
        arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(Input_Features='line2', 
                                               Geometry_Properties='LINE_START_MID_END', 
                                               Length_Unit='METERS', 
                                               Coordinate_System=output_spatial_reference)

        #Create third line, starting from end of line1
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features='line1', out_layer='line1_lyr')

        arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view='line1_lyr', in_field='WP', 
                                join_table='project_view', 
                                join_field='WP')
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='line1_lyr', out_feature_class='line1b')
        arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(in_table='line1b', 
                                              out_featureclass='line3', 
                                              x_field='END_X', 
                                              y_field='END_Y', 
                                              distance_field='Baseline_length', 
                                              distance_units='METERS', 
                                              bearing_field='Baseline', 
                                              spatial_reference=output_spatial_reference)
        #Create fourth line, starting from end of line2
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features='line2', out_layer='line2_lyr')
        arcpy.AddJoin_management(in_layer_or_view='line2_lyr', in_field='WP', 
                                 join_table='project_view', 
                                 join_field='WP')
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='line2_lyr', out_feature_class='line2b')
        arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(in_table='line2b', 
                                               out_featureclass='line4', 
                                               x_field='END_X', 
                                               y_field='END_Y', 
                                               distance_field='Transect_width', 
                                               distance_units='METERS', 
                                               bearing_field='Transect', 
                                               spatial_reference=output_spatial_reference)

        arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=['line1','line2','line3','line4'], output='lines')
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features='lines', out_feature_class='lines_diss', 
                                 multi_part=True)
        arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(in_features='lines_diss', 
                                                out_feature_class='rectangle', 
                                                geometry_type='RECTANGLE_BY_AREA')
        arcpy.Append_management(inputs='rectangle', target=outfc, schema_type='NO_TEST')
```

[image]